# Lambda properties in C# - "Invalid token in class, struct, or interface member declaration"

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

In my project the properties are assigned like this:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("message", IsRequired = true)]
        public string message=> this["message"] as string;
```

When I compile my code I get this error:

> Invalid token '"message"' in class, struct, or interface member
>   declaration    Error  4   Identifier expected

Comment: Are you compiling against the correct version of C# (6.0)?

Comment: From your tags, is it safe to assume you are *not* using C#6 (MSBuild 14)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expression-bodied members [were introduced in C# 6.0](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2015/05/14/c.net-little-wonders-expression-bodied-members-in-c-6.aspx). You will have to compile against that version or use the legacy member syntax.

As a workaround you could do this:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("message", IsRequired = true)]
public string message {
    get {
        return this["message"] as string;
    }
}
```